# Separar campos por TAB

Tags: php, mysql, script

Estou fazendo uma consulta `SQL` e retornando os resultados em um arquivo .txt, até ai tudo bem!

Agora foi solicitado que o o conteudo do arquivo seja separado por `TAB (ASCII 9 )`.

Pesquisei bastante e vi que preciso colocar o `chr(9)` que representa o `TAB`, porém não estou conseguindo aplica-lo ao meu código (bem simples, por sinal). Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Abaixo está o código que estou usando:

```
if ($resultado > 0 ) {
while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$cpf=$mostrar["CodCgcCpf"];
$nome=$mostrar["Nome"];
$email=$mostrar["email"];
$endereco=$mostrar["Endereco"];
$numero=$mostrar["numero_predio"];
$complemento=$mostrar["complemento"];
$bairro=$mostrar["Bairro"];
$cidade=$mostrar["Cidade"];
$uf=$mostrar["UF"];
$cep=$mostrar["Cep"];
$telefone=$mostrar["Fone"];

$conteudo = "";
$conteudo .= "".PHP_EOL;
$conteudo = "$cpf;$nome;$email;$endereco;$numero;$complemento;$bairro;$cidade;$uf;$cep;$telefone ";
$conteudo .= "".PHP_EOL;
$name = "clientes.txt";
$file = fopen ($name, 'a+'); 
fwrite($file, $conteudo);
fclose($file);
}
} else {
}
```

---

Fiz desse jeito também.

```
function truncate( $string, $max_length )
{
   return substr( ( string ) $string, 0, ( int ) $max_length );
}

function prepare_string_to_column( $string, $limit )
{
   return ( str_pad( ( string ) $string, ( int ) $limit ) );
}

$fp = fopen( 'clientes.txt', 'a' );


$line1 = array(
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'CPF', 11 ), 13 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'NOME', 30 ), 32 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'EMAIL', 30 ), 32 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'ENDERECO', 40 ), 42 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'NUMERO', 6 ), 8 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'COMPLEMENTO', 11 ), 13 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'BAIRRO', 15 ), 17 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'CIDADE', 15 ), 17 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'UF', 2 ), 4 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'CEP', 10 ), 12 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( 'TELEFONE', 12 ), 14 )


);

fwrite( $fp, implode( null, $line1 ) . PHP_EOL );

while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

$cpf=$mostrar["CodCgcCpf"];
$nome=$mostrar["Nome"];
$email=$mostrar["email"];
$endereco=$mostrar["Endereco"];
$numero=$mostrar["numero_predio"];
$complemento=$mostrar["complemento"];
$bairro=$mostrar["Bairro"];
$cidade=$mostrar["Cidade"];
$uf=$mostrar["UF"];
$cep=$mostrar["Cep"];
$telefone=$mostrar["Fone"];

$line2 = array(


   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$cpf", 11 ), 13 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$nome", 30 ), 32 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$email", 30 ), 32 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$endereco", 40 ), 42 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$numero", 6 ), 8 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$complemento", 11 ), 13 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$bairro", 15 ), 17 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$cidade", 15 ), 17 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$uf", 2 ), 4 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$cep", 10 ), 12 ),
   prepare_string_to_column( truncate( "$telefone", 12 ), 14 )

);


fwrite( $fp, implode( null, $line2 ) . PHP_EOL );

}
fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: Use `"\t"` para tabs

Comment: O `"\t"` equivale a um TAB da tabela ASCII?

Comment: Sim, considere como um atalho.

Answer (score -1):

Testei algumas formas, concatenando ou não:

```
$tab=chr(9).chr(9).chr(9);#aqui vai quantas tabs vc qser
$conteudo = "";

while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $conteudo .= "".PHP_EOL;
    $conteudo .= "$cpf;$tab$nome;$tab$email;$tab$endereco;$tab$numero;$tab$complemento;$tab$bairro;$tab$cidade;$tab$uf;$tab$cep;$tab$telefone ";
    $conteudo .= "".PHP_EOL;
}
$name = "clientes.txt";
$file = fopen ($name, 'a+'); 
fwrite($file, $conteudo);
fclose($file);
```

Note que em `$tab` eu defini o valor de `chr(9)`, que é o `ASCII` para tabulação, adicionei entre os campos da variável `$conteúdo` e imprimi o resultado assim:

```
cpf;    nome;   email;  endereco;   numero; complemento;    bairro; cidade; uf; cep;    telefone
```

Outra coisa que percebi foi que ai no código que vc compartilhou, a variável `$conteúdo` logo após o primeiro `PHP_EOL` não estava sendo concatenada constando apenas um `=` sem o `.`, tomei a liberdade de adicioná-lo à minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo! o Resultado saiu assim... 
`CPF NOME EMAIL ENDERECO NUMERO COMPLEMENTO BAIRRO CIDADE UF CEP TELEFONE` 
`11111111111 TESTE DA SILVA MESQUITA  RUA CORONEL MEIRELES 1850  PENHA SAO PAULO SP 03612000 2244024`

Eu conseguiria alinhar em colunas?

Comment: como assim alinhar as colunas, elas não estão em ordem e em linhas diferentes?

Comment: Gostaria que ficasse mais ou menos assim.

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figura-4-Amostra-do-layout-inicial-dos-arquivos-TXT-Tomando-se-como-exemplo-a-primeira_fig3_327057857

Comment: ué amigo, só colocar mais tabs entre os campos, vou editar

Comment: Então, acredito que não irá funcionar dessa forma, porque a pessoa que vai ler, vai identificar a separação do tab como outro campo e no exemplo que você deu, teria 3 tabs ou seja, três campos em branco!

Comment: eu queria definir um tamanho mesmo para coluna Ex: coluna `CPF´ 11 caracteres - Coluna Nome: 30 caracteres e assim por diante e ao final desses caracteres um tab... Eu consegui fazer até as colunas ali na minha pergunta . Mas não consegui definir o tab no conceito que usei